# Share file from url

Tags: file, flutter, download, share

I'm working on a project that needs to share a pdf file and that file is stored in the firebase storage.

I've researched different sharing libs and all seems to share files from the internal storage or share the url directly as text (this could be an option, but product team doesn't want it).

So my question is, is there a way different than manually download the pdf, save it in the internal storage and then share it as any file?

This seems to me like a not so strange use case, so someone may have a better solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package to share files https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share

```
Future<void> _shareMixed() async {
try {
  final ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
  final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image2.png');
  final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/addresses.csv');

  await Share.files(
      'esys images',
      {
        'esys.png': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'bluedan.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'addresses.csv': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
      },
      '*/*',
      text: 'My optional text.');
} catch (e) {
  print('error: $e');
}
}
```

full example can be found in following link code

Comment: Currently the lib has a bug, but works. Much easier, thanks! ;)